# Is it okay to use rudraksha Mala that's used for wearing to use to chant Gayatri Mantra?

Tags: gayatri-mantra, rudraksha

Is it okay to use rudraksha Mala (108 beads, 5 faced) that I'm wearing to use to chant Gayatri Mantra? Or do I need a new one to use specifically for chanting Gayatri?  If so, is there specific no of beads to be used to chant Gayatri?

Comment: I don't think it should matter if you are able to hold it comfortably in your hands while chanting. There are 108+1 beads in the japa malas as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Yes according to the **[Devi Bhagwat Puran](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57383.html)** discussion on Rudraksha rosaries, it is mentioned:

> Worship the rosary with the Mantra of that Devata for which it is intended. **One is to wear the Rudrākṣa rosary on one’s head, neck or ear and controlling oneself, one should make japam with the rosary.** On the neck, head, breast, or the ears or on the arms, the rosary should he held with the greatest devotion. What is the use in saying about it so often? It is highly meritorious and commendable to hold always the Rudrākṣam. Especially on such occasions as taking baths, making gifts, making japams, performing the Homas,or sacrifices to Viṣve Devas, in performing the Poojās of the Devas,in making Prāyascittams (penances), in the time of Śrādh and in the time of initiation, it is highly necessary to hold Rudrākṣam. A Brāhmin is sure to go to hell if he performs any Vaidik act without wearing any Rudrākṣam.

So clearly the same rosary of Rudraksh beads can be worn by a person as well as used for mantra-japa as well.